# Eclipse and Git : how to create a war from an old branch

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I ve always been struggling with Git on Eclipse, and now I have a serious problem.

I 've created a branch A which is the one I used to deploy on the Internet.
I also have a branch B which is the one I work to test.

Now I ve been ask to deploy A with only one feature of B. On Eclipse if I switch from Branch B to A, make my change and if I export, war I will have a war created with most of B Features.

How can I have a war with only my B selected feature ?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solutions to this would be to create a branch from master and reset to the point of your merge (B -> A). 
If there are commits that you don't need that happened before your commit(s), otherwise try cherry-picking (have a look at: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)